# OpsHub migration failures, Could not load file or assembly WorkItemTracking.Proxy

Tags: opshub, azure-devops

I am getting lots of errors like the below since installing the latest version of the OpsHub Free Migration Utility.  Any help would be appreciated.

> OH-TFS-Connector-0017: Could not load attachment with URL http://MYDomain.co.uk:1336/tfs/TeamProjectsCollection/WorkItemTracking/v1.0/AttachFileHandler.ashx?FileID=823&FileName=Bug+on+Website+BackOffice+YearOnYearScores.msg. Server Error : OH-TFS-Connector-0051: Operation failed getAttachmentInputStream. Server Error : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error would seem to indicate that you need the [Team Foundation Server object model](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f30e5cc7-036e-449c-a541-d522299445aa) installed. The specific assembly version looks like TFS 2012.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, it does seem to be working now.  Strange how that was required when the previous minor version of the app worked ok, cheers!